# This is my php for viewing user profile

Tags: php, mysql

**My Profile php**

```
<?php
//profile.php

require_once 'includes/global.php';

//check to see if they're logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// finding user and viewing it
$tools = new FindUser();
$user = $tools->get($_REQUEST['userID']);

?>
```

This is my php for viewing user profile.

http://mywebsite.com/profile.php?userID=5 its working fine in this way.

i want my code to check if user is available in database for example if i add `?userID=10` which is not present in database it gives out mysql error or even if i use `http://mywebsite.com/profile.php`then also it give error.

so now i want if user is not available in database it should give that user is not available and when we use simple `http://mywebsite.com/profile.php` it should give auto add it to `userID=1` OR REDIRECT it to home.php

If there is other way of doing this please let me know. well im very newbie in this field

Thanks for looking my question and answering :)

**Solved**

```
<?php
//profile.php

require_once 'includes/global.php';

//check to see if they're logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

$UserID = $_GET['userID'];
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$UserID'");

$CheckNumber = mysql_num_rows($CheckQuery);
if ($CheckNumber !== 1)
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

// finding user and viewing it
$tools = new FindUser();
$user = $tools->get($_REQUEST['userID']);

?>
```

Comment: Offtopic: UserFinder->find sounds better than FindUser->get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `MySQL` As it's depreciated,

If you really wish to use MySQL You could check at the start of the script if there is a row count for the User ID, Example:

```
<?
    $UserID = $_GET['UserID'];
    $UserID = mysql_real_escape_string($UserID);
    $CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='$UserID'");

    $CheckNumber = mysql_num_rows($CheckQuery);
    if ($CheckNumber !== 1)
    {

    // Do something If user is Not Found
    // Redirect to Another Page OR Something
    }
?>
```

Comment: im adding and trying your codes and will vote up as soon it works :)

Comment: i can now move smarter one to any page i want like im doing index.php

Comment: Glad to be of some assistance, Probably not as professional as people would like, but the code gets it done and feel free to contact me if you have any other problems over at _admin@slayer-productions.com_

Comment: You could use [intval](http://php.net/intval) `$UserID = intval($_GET['UserID']);`

Comment: i tried userID=ggggggggg' but does seems any security flaw and thanks @Prasanth again :)

Answer (score 1):

than check that query give with result if it wont found data in database than redirect

```
$result = mysql_query(...);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=1){ //

 header("Location:signup.php");
  exit();
}
```

You shouldn't use MySQL As it's depreciated, either use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: im adding and trying your codes and will vote up as soon it works :)